# Multiline equation with cases

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, align

I am trying to get a system of equations, that will have cases only on some of the equations. I made this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begingroup
\begin{equation*}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\begin{array}{rl}
    b_0 & = p(0)\\
\begin{rcases}
    1^n+b_{n-1}1^{n-1}+\ldots+b_11+b_0&= p(1)\\
    2^n+b_{n-1}2^{n-1}+\ldots+b_12+b_0&= p(2)\\
    \hdotsfor{2}\\
    (n-1)^n+b_{n-1}(n-1)^{n-1}+\ldots+b_1(n-1)+b_0&= p(n-1)\\
\end{rcases}
\quad
\text{\parbox{4cm}{reset}}
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

But for the output I get is this:

[image]

I've tried with `eqnarray`, but my first equation is flushed right :
Is there a way to make the first one aligned with the rest?

Comment: Is a & befor `begin{rcases}` enough?

Comment: Nope, that just pushes the first equation to the left side, doesn't align it with the `=` sign :\

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can work with the package `bigdelim`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bigdelim}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{r@{{}={}}ll}
    b_0 &  p(0) &\\
    1^n+b_{n-1}1^{n-1}+\ldots+b_11+b_0& p(1) &\rdelim\}{4}{4mm}[reset]\\
    2^n+b_{n-1}2^{n-1}+\ldots+b_12+b_0& p(2)& \\
    \hdotsfor{2}& \\
    (n-1)^n+b_{n-1}(n-1)^{n-1}+\ldots+b_1(n-1)+b_0& p(n-1)&\\
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

---

The package `bigdelim` are providing two commands `rdelimn` and `ldelim` both commands have the same syntax: 3 mandatory arguments and one optional argument.

The syntax is:

```
\rdelim{<delimiter>}{<rows>}{<width>}[<text next to the delimiter>]
```

The second and third argument is directly passed to `multirow`.

Comment: Can you please explain where the `4mm` come from?

Comment: @HendrikVogt: Done

Comment: @Marco: Ah, thanks. May I ask why you chose `4mm` for the width?

Comment: @HendrikVogt: It just a value ;-) -- In the example above there is no need for a specific value.

Comment: @Marco: Hmm, OK. By the way, I noticed that `bigdelim` unfortunately doesn't take into account the `\arraystretch` (which is `1` in your case, so the output is great).

Comment: @HendrikVogt: This is a bug of `bigdelimn`. Some years ago I wrote a small package with the same functionality but it took `arraystretch` into account. I had never uploaded the package. However it's important to mentioned that the bug is a result of `multirow`.

Comment: @Marco: Finally I see the effect of the `4mm`: the choice influences whether the whole construction will be centered in the math display. With `4mm` it's not because the brace construction is wider than that. It's not so nice that the user has to care about this number.

Comment: @HendrikVogt: The package is really old. Maybe David will provide a better solution with LaTeX3.